# Nextjs - How Do I Store A JWT in The Client's Browser That Can Persist A Browser Restart

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, jwt, use-state

I am making an app that involves creating a JWT that the client must "remember" for at least 24 hours. I know that sounds strange but this app I'm building involves something called "Litprotocol" which does decentralized authorization. When a user logs in/registers, a JWT is created by a series of 3rd party servers, and the resulting JWT is valid for 24 hours. Since this JWT involves a somewhat intricate process, for efficiencies sake, I don't want to create a new JWT every time the user tries to login. The app is written in Nextjs and I tried to use the following code to attempt creating a persistently stored variable name "storedVal."

```
export default function Home(props: any) {

...
...
...

  const [storedVal, setStoredVal] = useState(String);

  function storePersistence() {
    setStoredVal('I set this');
  }

  function printPersistence() {
    console.log(storedVal);
  }

  return (

    <>
      <VStack>
        <Heading as='h3'>Connect to see unity app</Heading>

        {
          !connected ? <Button variant='solid' onClick={connect}>Connect</Button> : <Text>Now you can click on protected path link at the bottom</Text>
        }<br></br>

        <Button variant='solid' onClick={storePersistence}>Store Persistence</Button>
        <Button variant='solid' onClick={printPersistence}>Check Persistence</Button>

      </VStack>
    </>
  )
}
```

The "Store Persistence" and "Check Persistence" buttons and functions are the relevant code. This doesn't work. As soon as I restart my browser, "storedVal" is cleared. So how can I make "storedVal" persist browser and possibly computer restarts?

Comment: Store it in `localStorage` when JWT is sent to client. When user closes the site and open again that time fetch JWT from `localStorage` and check if it's valid or not and do the needful. Refer [Blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/) for localstorage. You can set JWT as follows `localStorage.setItem("jwt", value)` and fetch it `localStorage.getItem("jwt")`
`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I made a psuedo code gist showing how to implement persistence in my above code https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/5c387f161223b11fafc914966651bb9b. If you make this into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: How to convert comment into answer I don't know except copy pasting it. Glad it helped you it's basic idea/mechanism for persisting. You can use new hooks also for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Idea/Mechanism for persisting data via `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` in client side.

1. Store it in `localStorage` when JWT is sent to client.
2. When user closes the site and open again that time fetch JWT from `localStorage` and check if it's valid or not and do the needful. Refer [Blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/) for `localstorage`.
3. You can set JWT as follows `localStorage.setItem("jwt", value)` and fetch it `localStorage.getItem("jwt")`

You can use hooks/function provided by library/framework as well it does work on similar idea.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from [@GodWin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10995550/godwin)'s comment, you could also use this hook which I love: [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/). There's many variants of it and you can certainly write your own. It basically loads in a `localStorage` value into a hook given a key, for which you can provide a default value.

You can use it just like a `useState`:

```js
function Home() {
  const key = "local-jwt"
  const defaultValue = null
  const [jwt, setJWT] = useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue)

  // use your jwt somewhere

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```